# rspec context blocks not executing in the correct order

Tags: ruby, rspec

Using rspec and the selenium webdriver for chrome, ive written code that has this format:

```
describe x do
  [some code]
  context y do
    [some code]
    it a do
      [more code]
    end
  end
  context z do
    [some other code]
    it b do
      [even more code]
    end
  end
end
```

It intuitively seems like the program flow should go straight down the program, going into context y and then executing the 'it a do' statement. However, after it finishes with the [some code] in context y, it immediately skips to context z without hitting the it block.

Is there a command line argument or some other piece of code that needs to be included in order for the program flow to work linearly down through the code?

Answer (score 3):

Rspec randomizes the order of the tests.

Each test is supposed to be working and should not be dependent of its order compared to the other tests.

You can, however, bypass this behaviour if you run rspec with the `--order default` option